# Function whose derivation(s) is the same function with a different input

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

**Discrete and continuous derivation of the harmonic series function:**

Discrete function (with increment $= 1$):

$$\Delta_n^0(n) = \frac 1n$$

$$\Delta_n^1(n) = -\frac{1}{n^2-n} = \Delta_n^1(-n^2-n)$$

Continuous function:

$$f(x) = \frac 1x$$

$$\frac{1/(x+d) - 1/x }{d} = \frac{-d}{d(x^2+xd)}  = \frac{-d}{dx(x+d)} = -\frac{1}{x^2 + xd} \\[2ex] \lim_{d\rightarrow 0} - \frac{1}{x^2 + xd} = -\frac{1}{x^2} = f'(x) = f(-x^2)$$

---

**What I've gathered:**

In both these cases, the first derivative is just the nonderivated function with a different input (the square of the input in the continuous function). I visualize that as just "pulling the graphed curve backwards". In the discrete function, more happens however. An expansion of the function's discontinuity happens along with the "retraction" of the function. The non-derivated function was discontinuous over $0$ (and thus an asymptote). The "asymptotic gap" is expanded in the derivation however, as the derivated function is discontinuous over $1$ as well.

---

**Questions:**

1. Is there a name for functions whose derivation(s) are just the non-derivated function with a different input? If so, is this property useful?
2. Is there a non-trivial function to which every derivation always possesses the aforementioned property?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to write $f'(x) = f(g(x))$ for some function $g$?  If so, a sufficient (but not necessary) condition would be if the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists.  Coz $g(x) = f^{-1}(f'(x))$.  E.g. in your second example:

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} \implies g(x) = f^{-1}(f'(x)) = \frac{1}{ -\frac{1}{x^2}} = -x^2$$

The same condition is sufficient for your question 2, i.e. writing $f''(x) = f(g(x))$ is possible if $g(x) = f^{-1}(f''(x))$ and so on.

I don't know of any name for this phenomenon.

You wrote:

> I visualize that as just "pulling the graphed curve backwards".

Well, I would not describe the function $g(x) = -x^2$ as just "pulling backwards" (on the horizontal axis).  It involves "stretching" and "mirroring" too, or even more complicated transformations if $g$ is more complex.

Comment: "It involves "stretching" and "mirroring" too, or even more complicated transformations if g is more complex." Yes, this was overlooked by me. Could you elaborate on what you mean by mirroring? I am not really completely sure about the stretching part either, but the formulation makes more intuitive sense to me.

Comment: I think I understand the "inverse as a sufficient condition" part of your answer. If $f(x)$ possesses an inverse, then $f′(x)=f(f^{−1}(h(x)))$, in which case $f′(x)=h(x)$. If we take $f^{−1}(h(x))$ to be it's own function, denoted $g(x)$, then $f(g(x))=f′(x)$, and naturally, $g(x)=f^{−1}(f'(x))$. This is quite trivial but it completely eluded me. [This is a new comment that fixes math typos in the old one]